# Customizing Stepper widget depending on step number

Tags: flutter

I have included a Stepper widget in my App.

Here you have the implementation:

```
Expanded(
              child: Stepper(
                controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                    {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                  return Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: onStepCancel,
                        child: Text('Previous'.tr().toString()),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: onStepContinue,
                        child: Text('Next'.tr().toString()),
                      ),

                    ],
                  );
                },
                steps: _stepper(),
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                currentStep: this._currentStep,
                onStepTapped: (step) {
                  setState(() {
                    this._currentStep = step;
                  });
                },
                onStepContinue: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (this._currentStep < this._stepper().length - 1) {
                      this._currentStep = this._currentStep + 1;
                    } else {
                      //your code
                      print('complete');
                    }
                  });
                },
                onStepCancel: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (this._currentStep > 0) {
                      this._currentStep = this._currentStep - 1;
                    } else {
                      this._currentStep = 0;
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),

            ),
```

I have included 6 steps.

Now, on every step both TextButtons are shown for methods onStepCancel and onStepContinue, but I would like to hide the TextButton for onStepCancel on step #1, and to hide the textButton for onStepContinue on step #6.

How can I implement both conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the controlsBuilder implementation：

[image]
[image]

```
List<Tuple2> tuples = [
  Tuple2(Icons.directions_bike, StepState.indexed, ),
  Tuple2(Icons.directions_bus, StepState.editing, ),
  Tuple2(Icons.directions_railway, StepState.complete, ),
  Tuple2(Icons.directions_boat, StepState.disabled, ),
  Tuple2(Icons.directions_car, StepState.error, ),
];

int _index = 0;    

controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, { VoidCallback? onStepContinue, VoidCallback? onStepCancel }){
    return Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 30,),
        if (_index != tuples.length - 1) ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: onStepContinue,
          child: Text("Next"),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 8,),
        if (_index != 0) ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: onStepCancel,
          child: Text("Back"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```